Why is my code not arranged vertically in Grid?
I am developing using React and MaterialUI. I encountered a strange issue where elements would not align vertically. Usually, I work on the backend, so I have almost no knowledge about frontend development, particularly about Grids. What could be the reason the following code does not align items vertically?
<Grid
  container
  direction="column"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
>
  <Box
    component="form"
    sx={{ "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" } }}
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
  >
    <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Email" variant="standard" />
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: "25ch" }} variant="standard">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
        Password
      </InputLabel>
      <Input
        id="standard-adornment-password"
        type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
            >
              {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </FormControl>
  </Box>
</Grid>

I want to arrange the input bars for email addresses and passwords vertically.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Thank you for commenting on my question!
Do you mean that you can't understand what the problem is with my code alone?

We need the compiled HTML/CSS which shows the problem, React code is not sufficient.

How do I provide the compiled HTML/CSS?
I tried to get the HTML/CSS in the developer tools in a local environment, but it is too long.
I would like to know the specific method.

Looking at your code, your Box component is what is causing you to not be able to vertically stack the elements.
If you are happy to use flex model instead of a grid system, you could implement it to vertically stack like this for example:
<Box
    component="form"
    sx={{
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
    }}
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
  >
    <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Email" variant="standard" />
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: "25ch" }} variant="standard">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
        Password
      </InputLabel>
      <Input
        id="standard-adornment-password"
        type={"password"}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
            ></IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </FormControl>
  </Box>


Thank you for answering my question!
Your answer solve my problem.
I would like to ask an additional question, can it ever be accomplished using Grid?
